# How to run testng.xml in bat file

Tags: batch-file, selenium

Im new to selenium webdriver and I want to schedule my test on windows server. So i intend to create a .bat file and use windows scheduler. This is my bat file. Please help me on this

> projectLocation=E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5
>
> cd %projectLocation%
>
> set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib*
>
> java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
>
> pause

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mit5J.png)

When i run the code getting some errors.

```
C:\Users\miskinr\Desktop    set projectLocation=E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5
C:\Users\miskinr\Desktop    cd E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5
C:\Users\miskinr\Desktop    set classpath=E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\bin;
E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\lib\*
C:\Users\miskinr\Desktop    java org.testng.TestNG E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\testng.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Automation\Webdrive (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init    (Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init    (Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:167)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1021)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
  C:\Users\miskinr\Desktop\project\HTML5\testng.xml
(The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init    (Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init    (Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:167)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1021)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
cd /d "%projectLocation%"
```

The `/d` switch changes the drive letter at the same time as the working directory, and the quotation marks treat the space as part of the pathname rather than as a token separator.  Also, for the same reason, you should quote the location in

```js
java org.testng.TestNG "%projectLocation%\testng.xml"
```

But since you fixed your `cd /d` line, you can leave out `%projectLocation%` anyway since that's already the current working directory now.

Not strictly applicable to the current situation, but whenever you set a variable to a string, it's good practice to quote the `"variable=value"` pair.

And finally, the `*` wildcard won't have the effect you expect I don't think.  You'll need to use a `for /d` loop to expand it, and delayed expansion to append `%classpath%` in that loop.

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "projectLocation=E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5"
cd /d "%projectLocation%"
set "cp=%CLASSPATH%"

rem // append *.jar recursively to cp
for /r %%I in (*.jar) do (
    if not defined cp (set "cp=%%~fI") else set "cp=%%~fI;!cp!"
)

java -cp "%cp%" org.testng.TestNG "testng.xml"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but still it didn't work.                                                              

E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5>java org.testng.TestNG "testng.xml"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
<br>
"Java Class file path - E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\bin\Automation"

"Lib folder path - E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\lib"

"Testng.XML path - E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5" </br>

Comment: Man, all I can do is point out the problems with your batch syntax.  I'm not familiar with Java programming or its environment.  My guess is that classpath needs to include the actual .jar files, not just the directories in which they live.  Try the edit and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

After cd %projectLocation%, the drive path is still in C:.

Perform cd E:\ to switch the driver. Since the testng.xml exists in E: drive and you are trying to run from C:\ File not found exception is triggered.

Try this:

```
projectLocation=E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5

cd %projectLocation%

set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib*

cd E:\

java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
```

Comment: I tried this.. but still it is not working

E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5>set projectLocation=E:\Automation\Webdrive
project\HTML5

E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5>cd E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5

E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5>set classpath=E:\Automation\Webdrive projec
t\HTML5\bin;E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\lib*

E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5>cd E:\

E:\>java org.testng.TestNG E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\testng.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

E:\>pause

Comment: My Folder paths are - 

"Java Class file path - E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\bin\Automation" "Lib folder path - E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5\lib" "Testng.XML path - E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5"

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, Just change as below.it will work

```
projectLocation=E:\Automation\Webdrive project\HTML5
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib*
cd..
E:

java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
```